# class member function variable pointing to another class function member

Tags: c++, class, pointers

can you please explain me why this code shows nothing except for the last std::cout line in main()? Checked through similar threads on stackoverflow.com, was not able to connect them to mine, is this pointing legal at all? I try to set a function pointer of a class to another class function:

```
#include <iostream>

class container;

class one {
public:
one() 
    { 
        eventsHandler = NULL; 
    };
~one() {}; 

void (container::*eventsHandler)();
};

class container {
public:
    container() 
    { 
        zone = new one;
        zone->eventsHandler = &container::events;
    };
    ~container()
    { 
        delete zone; 
    };

    one *zone;
    void events()
    {
        std::cout << "event handler is on..." << std::endl;
    };
};

int main()
{
    container *test = new container;
    test->zone->eventsHandler;

    std::cout << "just checker..." << std::endl;
    delete test;

    system("pause");
};
```

Comment: Im impressed by how fast you guys replied, thanks again to all, @songyuanyao answer looks working for me :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `operator->*` for calling the member function pointer, and assign `test` as the object which will be called on,

```
(test->*test->zone->eventsHandler)();
```

or more clear,

```
(test->*(test->zone->eventsHandler))();
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/e9xNsC)

Comment: thanks a lot, this one works good, I could not realize calling code should require more scopes, did not get full concept of class::*function here. First TEST-> is class from definition and following dereferencing is just link to assigned ZONE functionned parameter. Sorry for the words, need to check if I understood this technic right :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually *call* the function pointer, in line 38, as:

```
(test->*test->zone->eventsHandler)();
```

Comment: Sadly enough this just causes a compilation error because `test->zone->eventsHandler` is a pointer to a method of `container` not a pointer to an free function.

Comment: True, used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx to fix.

It's about 10 years ago I actually *used* member function pointers in C++, things are a bit rusty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an object to call a pointer to memeber function:

```
container *test = new container;
(test->*test->zone->eventsHandler)();
```

Here, `test` is the object, `test->zone->eventsHandler` is the pointer to member function that you have saved, and `operator->*` joins them.

So, it is very much like any other member function; however, you can switch which objects to call a member on:

```
container *first = new container;
container *second = new container;
(first->*second->zone->eventsHandler)();
// both pointers point to the same function
std::cout << (first->zone->eventsHandler == second->zone->eventsHandler) << std::endl;
```